# Create training and test folders and subfolders in R

Tags: r

I have a directory containing N sub-directories, where each sub-directory i is of one class N_i and there are N classes in total.

I want to create a training directory and test directory from this directory.

The training directory should contain N sub-directories, where each sub-directory is of one class and contains 80% of the original total number of samples in class N_i.

The test directory should contain N sub-directories, where each sub-directory is of one class and contains 20% of the samples in class N_i.

I know a lot of examples exist to sample directly in data frames in R. But no discussion on doing file manipulation like this. Is it possible to perform this in R?

Comment: Perhaps you're talking about [lists](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists)?

Comment: No I don't think so. I think one way to do is to create a vector of all the file names, and then use sample to select a portion of the files. Then use file.copy to copy these files to a new directory. Finally delete the copied files. It seems quite tedious. Repeat this process for each directory containing a single class. I was just wondering if there is an easier method someone has already explored....